# Windows Server Backup: New Disk & Keeping Backup History

Tags: windows, backup, windows-server-2008, iscsi

I have been doing backups for a couple of years on Win Server 2008R2 using Windows Server Backup. The 'drive' is attached via iSCSI and has been working fine. Well, now I have a new SAN devise and I want to backup to this using iSCSI instead of the old location--everything is working fine as far as mounting the drives--but specifically, is there any way I can copy over the backup *history* to the new drive? I need to completely remove the old drive from the system and only use the new drive. Currently I can do this but I don't know how to do this without losing years of incremental backup history.

If I add both drives to the backup schedule, will this copy the history from the first drive over to the second? thanks!

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd want to keep "years of incremental backup history".  Don't you periodically take a FULL backup?  And save several generations of full backups off-site?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is server admin/maintenance.

Comment: first, want to apologize if this is the wrong place to post regarding server maintenance. if so i will remove just let me know. @paulsm4 WinServBackup manages full/incrementals on it's own--i just don't want to lose the ability to restore files from a few weeks or months ago when changing backup drives. any idea how to achieve this? as far as offsite i'm going to push everything to the cloud for disaster recovery--taking physical disks offsite is sooo 2005 ;-)